# a basic Text to speech app not working

Tags: android

i tried the following on the emulator but the as the app starts it gives a runtime error . could someone please help me on this . Heres' the code i tried

```
package com.example.TextSpeaker;

import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;

public class TextSpeaker extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
private TextToSpeech mtts;
String test1="hello world";
String test2="hi i am working fine";
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent myintent = new Intent();
    myintent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(myintent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
}
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,Intent data)
    {
        if(requestcode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE)
        {
            if(resultcode==TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)
            {
                // success so create the TTS engine
                mtts = new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) this);
                mtts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                mtts.speak(test1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                mtts.speak(test2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            }
            else
            {
                //install the Engine
                Intent install = new Intent();
                install.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(install);
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: the error is :
the application TextSpeaker has stopped unexpectedly

Comment: the stack trace is http://pastebin.com/0asLcb5p

Comment: i did manage to get the app start but of the two strings it only speaks the last one how do i correct that?

Comment: did finally manage to run the app, but the problem now is that there is a delay of almost a second before the sound comes out, also i am unable to change the language

Comment: @pranay could you write in your solution as an answer (and accept it)? and your most recent comment could be submitted as its own question

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon this question well over a year after it was posted, but I'm going to go ahead and answer anyway, in the sheer hope it'll help anyone else who ends up here in the future.

I'm writing this against 2.1, so apologies if you were working with <2.1 (no tags on question)

There are a few things I can spot immediately that may give you a little grief.

Firstly, the following :

```
mtts.speak(test1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
mtts.speak(test2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

If I understand the [TextToSpeech API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) correctly, using QUEUE_FLUSH will flush out anything thats currently being spoken, so its possible that the second line is executing before the first has actually spoken, and you'd experience what you've stated above, that only the last one is being spoken.

Ideally, you only want one of those lines there, if the user puts in a different String, then just pass that through and let it flush out.

Next, you should invest in an onDestroy override, in here you can shutdown the mtts object, this prevents your app from hogging usage to the TTS engine, its always nice to free up resources when you're done with them, you wouldn't leave a ResultSet open now would you?!

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy
            () {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (mTts != null) {
            mTts.stop();
            mTts.shutdown();
        }

        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Also, as you state, it'll only speak English, because of the line you're using :

```
mtts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

That's easy to correct, just set a different locale. Perhaps have some buttons and set the locale accordingly. I believe that the Google TTS engine currently only supports English, French, German, Italian and Spanish, but 3rd party TTS engines may offer more.

If all else fails, I wrote a [tutorial here](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-a-really-easy-tutorial-on-how-to-use-text-to-speech-tts-and-how-you-can-enter-text-and-have-it-spoken/) that might be of use.

Good luck!